# Foreman: List VMs of a compute reourse

Tags: foreman

From Satellite 6/Foreman GUI, I can get the full list of VMs running on a compute resource. However, I cannot find a relevant command in hammer-cli. Do I miss something, or I just can't do it with hammer-cli?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cant do it with hammer-cli, so you dont miss something.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API for 1.13 (most recent version of Foreman), there's no way of getting that information. https://theforeman.org/api/1.13/index.html .

```
hammer
```

relies on the API, therefore there's no way to do it.

Time to write a plugin? http://projects.theforeman.org/projects/foreman/wiki/How_to_Create_a_Plugin

Comment: +1 Obviously a much needed feature